# apache rewrite two php variables and remove php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url:

```
http://www.website.co.uk/search.php?search=test&cat=catname
```

What I would like is:

```
http://www.website.co.uk/search/test/catname
```

I have tried this for the variables:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1
```

and this to hide the php extension:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

and it doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: And the fact that `^page/` doesn’t match on `search/` does really surprise you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?search=([^\s&]+)&cat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /search.php?search=$1&cat=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?search=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```